# why process.argv treats '*' as 'number' in node js repl?

Tags: javascript, node.js

when I give +, -, / as an input it works. But in case of *, it doesn't work.

```
console.log(process.argv);
let num1 = Number.parseInt(process.argv[2]);
let sign = process.argv[3];
let num2 = Number.parseInt(process.argv[4]);
if (sign === '+') {
  console.log(`Summation is ${num1 + num2}`);
} else if (sign === '-') {
  console.log(`Substraction is ${num1 - num2}`);

} else if (sign === '*') {
  console.log(`Multiplication is ${num1 * num2} `);
} else if (sign === '/') {
 console.log(`Division is ${num1 / num2} `);
}
```

Comment: * likely has special meaning on the command line. Which shell are you using to invoke the node script (windows command/powershell/bash etc.?)

Comment: I an using zsh shell

Comment: May be take a look at this question/answer over on [su] -https://superuser.com/questions/584249/using-wildcards-in-commands-with-zsh

Comment: FWIW, `process.argv` doesn't "treat" arguments as anything, they're all strings.

Answer (score 1):

The * isn't being treated as a number, it's being interpreted by the shell.

The * operator in zshell is a shortcut for file globbing. Possibly in other shells as well, but you said you were using zsh (as am I).

I tried running  your program and it interpolates all the files in the local directory in between the two numbers in the equation.

My recommendation is to use `x` as your multiplication sign to avoid it.